# Get NSString from HeaderView Section on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want to get a NSString out of the table HeaderView that's on top that moment. Because I want to implent it in ScrollViewDidScroll so one label changes when the header view changes.

Didn't find any clues on the web how to do this

Thanks!

Comment: One UILabel on top to display the current Section title name that's on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no predefined method by which you can get top section. There is one trick by which you can achieve it. First get indexPath for all visible cells.

```
NSArray *visible = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];

NSIndexPath *indexpath = (NSIndexPath*)[visible objectAtIndex:0];
```

Now you can get section value by indexpath.section. After getting this section you can get string from your data array for this section.

Comment: Hi @sjors you have only accepted my answer, also can you upvote it.